# Loop with changing table names in R

Tags: r, loops

I have nine table with names:

```
table1, table2, table3, ... table9
```

And would like to do this:

```
res_table1 <- mirt(data = table1, model = 2, itemtype= "graded")
res_table2 <- mirt(data = table2, model = 2, itemtype= "graded")
...
res_table9 <- mirt(data = table9, model = 2, itemtype= "graded")
```

Is it possible to use a loop instead? like this:

```
for (ii in c(1:9)){
  tmp_tbl_name <- paste("res_table",ii,sep = "")
  assign(tmp_tbl_name, mirt(data = table1, model = 2, itemtype= "graded"))
}
```

I have no idea how to deal with the `data = table1` part....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful

```
lapply(mget(paste('table', 1:9, sep='')), mirt, model = 2, itemtype= "graded")
```

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
for (ii in c(1:9)){
  tmp_tbl_name <- paste("res_table",ii,sep = "")
  assign(tmp_tbl_name, mirt(data = get(paste("table",ii,sep = "")), model = 2, itemtype= "graded"))}
```

Comment: it won't work in a loop, tmp_tbl_name is a variable name not the  table....